# Python - using "for" loop to output html content

Tags: python, html

I am outputting an HTML file in Python. Inside the HTML, I have a table showing the keys and values from the dictionary in the Python file and I think I have to use a loop to display the table data in this case. But I'm confused about using python to output html content. I have tried using<% %> which is supposed to allow Python code in HTML but it didn't work..

```
 message = """
        <html>
        <body>
        <h1>Counting words</h1>
        <table border = 1>
        <tr>
        <th>Words</th>
        <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
        <% for key, value in wordDict.items(): %>
            <% if value >= 10: %>
                <tr>
                <td><% print(key) %></td>
                <td><% print(value) %></td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>"""
        f.write(message)
        f.close()
```

Comment: for using <% %> syntax, you first have to install template engine for Python.
http://jinja.pocoo.org/

Comment: @HarshaBiyani is there anyway that I can do it without using <% %> syntax?

Comment: no.. you have to use any 1 template language or any framework..

Answer (score 3):

You can use string formatting to insert dynamic values into string:

```
message = """
            <html>
            <body>
            <h1>Counting words</h1>
            <table border = 1>
            <tr>
            <th>Words</th>
            <th>Count</th>
            </tr>
            {0}
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>"""

wordDict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}

insert = []
for k, v in wordDict.items():
    insert.append("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>".format(k, v))
print(message.format(''.join(insert)))
```

output:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Counting words</h1>
    <table border = 1>
    <tr>
    <th>Words</th>
    <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>b</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>c</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. When using Joomla, you have to have finishing tags which look like this: <% endfor %> and <% endif %> and I am not sure abou the *:* after the for loop, try this if it's not workinng, play around with it

```
message = """
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Counting words</h1>
    <table border = 1>
    <tr>
    <th>Words</th>
    <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
    <% for key, value in wordDict.items() %>
        <% if value >= 10 %>
            <tr>
            <td><% print(key) %></td>
            <td><% print(value) %></td>
            </tr>
         <% endif %>
    <% endfor %>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>"""
    f.write(message)
    f.close()
```